# How to create WebApi Model from both Url and Body?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to develop an api method as follows

POST /dinner/dinnerId/application

which is the same as POST /application (Similar to POST requests [here](http://developers.asana.com/documentation/#tasks))

I defined a route so that /dinner/dinnerId/application goes to /application

```
   routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name:"DinnerApplicationApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/dinner/{dinnerId}/{controller}"
                );
```

And in my ApplicationController (which is an api controller)

```
[ModelValidationFilter]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]ApplicationApiModel application, int dinnerId)
        {
            //this will work when invoked from route /dinner/dinnerId/application and without ModelValidationFilter
            application.dinnerId = dinnerId;
            if (123456 == application.dinnerId)
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            else
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

Now, in case of the first route, I should set the dinnerId from the value in the route. But in the second case the dinnerId would be set from the body. How do I achieve this in WebApi? I was setting the dinnerId from the route as shown above. But when I put the ModelValidationFilter, the request fails as dinnerId is a required field in ApplicationApiModel.

```
public class ApplicationApiModel 
    {
        [Required]
        public int DinnerId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public AttendeeApiModel Attendee { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

So basically, I want to be able to use both the routes and have my ModelValidation conditions pass as well.